# Highcharts not showing colors in charts

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, angular-cli

Hi I have a couple of charts showing up in my app. I am using Angular-Highcharts package and for some reason the colors dont show up properly in my chart.

[image]

I inspected using chrome dev tools and it shows that the fill is transparent.

I also have a sunburst chart implemented and it works just fine.

I even tried the demo code form [here](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes) but its still the same with the demo code.

I kinda get a feel its got to do with the compiler.

Anyone experienced this and fixed this? Please advice.

This is a screenshot of the demo code on my machine.

[image]

I did it in [Stackblitz](https://hello-angular-6.stackblitz.io) and it works fine. The same code is running on my local machine as well as on my server.

Comment: Just a long shot have you tried `encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None` in your component?

Comment: No mate. I havent tried that. I’ll try and report back.

Comment: Tried it. Didnt work.

Comment: It's hard to find out what can cause the described problem, without any example where it occurs. Most probably it's caused by wrong angular configuration or somewhere in your code, you left some style definition for that element. Need more info about your code.

Comment: I tried the same in stackblitz and it works, but not on my machine nor on my server.